# How can I get my contacts back from my Google account

Tags: contacts, google-account

I had saved my contacts to my Google account in my old phone.
I signed in with my google account in my new mobile. The contacts were visible for around 5 minutes but they disappeared later.

Does this have to do with the person who has my old phone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a factory reset on your old phone?
Sign in to your google account and verify that the contacts are still there.

https://contacts.google.com/preview/all